# How to optimize requireJS application setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a working application using `requirejs`, which I'm trying to optimize. I'm launching the application in 2 steps:

First I start with a setup file `setup.js`, which I'm calling from the page source code:

```
<script data-main="../js/setup" src="../js/l/require/require.js"></script>
```

This file contains my require setup

```
var IS_LOCAL = /(:\/\/localhost|file:\/\/)/.test(document.location.href);

requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: (IS_LOCAL ? 2 : 45),
    baseUrl: "../js",
    paths: {
        intro: 'intro',
        overrides: 'overrides',
        jquery: 'l/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min',
        mobile: 'l/jquery-mobile/jquery-mobile-1.3pre.min',
        multiview: 'p/multiview/multiview.min',
        respond: 'p/respond/respond.min',
        i18next: 'p/i18next.min.js'
      },
  shim: {
    'overrides': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'mobile': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'multiview': { deps: ['jquery', 'mobile'] },
    'respond': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'i18next': { deps: ['jquery'] }
  }
});
// launch application - works, but I'm not happy with it
requirejs('overrides','jquery','mobile','multiview','respond','i18next','intro'],
    function (overrides, $, mobile, multiview, respond, i18next, Intro) {
      'use strict';
      Intro.start(overrides, $, mobile, multiview, respond, i18next);
     }
 );
```

This "triggers" my application controller `intro.js`, which looks like this:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';
     var start = function () {
        require(['overrides','jquery','mobile','multiview','respond','i18next'], 
            function () {
                // stuff
            }
        ); // end require
     } // end start
     return {
        "start": start
     };
 });
```

I'm still figuring out my way with requireJS, so while the above initializes correctly, I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle. Specifically I'm wondering:

**Questions:**
1) In my setup.js file, I'm triggering `Intro.start()` with plenty of parameters. Do I need the parameters there or should I put them inside `intro.js` when I'm doing my second require call?
2) Do I need the first require at all, because I'm requiring all files and then trigger a "file" (intro), which requires everything again?
3) How do I make objects available in intro.js? Say I need the `i18next` object inside `intro.js` to do some manual translations. Do I export in the shim and pass along through my two requires?

Thanks for some insights!

Comment: Have you considered splitting the library configuration part and the actual bootstrapping of your site? You'd point the requirejs data-main to some lib.js which contains all the paths. Then you can have any setup.js that is specifically targeted to the site at hand. The separation of concern will also increase maintainability of your library modules and not polute them too much with app logic.

Comment: So you mean the `data-main` should include include the requireJS "config", while my `intro.js` "site handler" should be called with a separate `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: Yes, although I consider configuration to be an override of a default. So your 'lib.js' should have as little configuration as all libraries will have relative paths to lib.js and all library level configuration used should be application independent. As the libraries are relative to the data-main url called, you don't need to define paths. If you would have jquery.js next to libs.js, you can use require(['jquery']) anywhere. Furthermore your intro.js wouldn't need to be a define(), but can be a require() of the modules you need for the specific functionality.